# Conveying the idea of "balancing conflicting interests"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, connotation

I'm looking for a less wordy way (either single word, phrase or even a metaphor or word picture) to convey the idea of the tension you feel when you have to balance two conflicting interests.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You're ***conflicted*** (or ***torn*** if you want an even shorter word)..

Comment: I hope this doesn't sound too nit-picking, but I see a substantial difference between a "conflict of interest" (incompatible obligations) and "conflicting interests" (interests that may be incompatible if pursued to their fullest extent but that may be reconciled through compromise). I'm not at all sure that a "conflict of interest" can be "balanced."

Comment: Nice distinction Sven.  It's a good point.

Comment: @phpmeh  I think the phrase in the title should be "conflicting interests" just as you posted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cognitive dissonance** is one possibility

> cognitive dissonance
>
> noun
>
> :  psychological conflict resulting from incongruous beliefs and
>   attitudes held simultaneously
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cognitive%20dissonance)

EDIT

Having seen FumbleFingers' 'conflicted', I think that's probably closer for your context.

Answer (score 2):

You feel as if you were **on the horns of a dilemma**.  In this case, not that the consequence of either decision would bring you an unpleasant result, but discarding one of them would.

> - [dilemma](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=between+the+cross+and+the+sword&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Jim9VaPIF6iB8QeYwIDABQ&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=dilemma+meaning) (noun) "a situation in which a difficult choice has to be made between two or more alternatives, especially equally undesirable ones."